# Discord JS external files

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

For creating my bot I have an index class which is getting a bit large, I would like to split it into individual classes for the functions.

For example, I'm wanting to put `client.on('messageReactionAdd'` and `client.on('messageReactionRemove'` into their own class, and then call them from the index.

How would I be able to achieve this?

Comment: What is an index class? Are you sure you want their own classes? Don't you just want to have handler functions in different files and import those?

Comment: The index class is my main file, I import the command files into it, however I have the main bot functions in the index too, so was wondering if I could just create a file called `reactions.js` and then import that instead of having the entire method in the main class, cause it would probably help with organisation and finding problems in the future

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out, my JavaScript knowledge isn't as clear as I thought.
Just had to require the external file and then call it in the ready function